# how to use a sql select statement to return a recordset in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database that has a table with the following columns:

`ID`, `StudentID`, `SchoolYear`, `Semester`, `ClassYear`, `CourseNumber`, `Class Number`.

I am using a form with combo boxes to get the StudentID and the SchoolYear and I want to get a record set of the StudentID and SchoolYear entered on the form.  I am using the following code but it does not seem to filter down to the correct records.

I have tried this:

```
x = Year.Value
y = ID.Value
strSQL = "select CourseNumber from T_ClassEnroll where StudentID = " & y & " and SchoolYear = " & x
Set recSet = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
count = recSet.RecordCount
```

the `count` comes back with 42 which is the number of rows for the `StudentID` but it does not filter it down to the `SchoolYear`.  There should only be 7 records.

I have also tried this sql statement with the same results

```
strSQL = "SELECT T_ClassEnroll.StudentID, T_ClassEnroll.SchoolYear, T_ClassEnroll.CourseNumber FROM T_ClassEnroll WHERE (((T_ClassEnroll.StudentID)=" & y & ") AND ((T_ClassEnroll.SchoolYear)=" & x & "))"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Display your SQL after building it and run it in the query designer to see what you get. Fix if incorrect syntax; if syntax ok, then verify you are actually invoking that query where expected.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271). Please add the output of `Debug.Print strSQL` to your question. Everything *seems* to be in order, though.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I ran the query as you suggested Wayne and the results came back correctly with the 7 entries.  I also added the output after the sql statement and it looks ok.  I still can not figure out why it will not return the correct value in the vb application.  I am getting frustrated, any other thoughts?

Comment: Where is your code located? You should use the 'After_Update' event for the combo box (make sure to test if no selection made for one of the combo boxes). Maybe post the full code (i.e. where do you set 'dbs'?

Comment: I thought through the sql statement to figure out why it ran in the query but no in the code an the only difference is the variables.  I changed the variables for Y and X to aa and bb and it seems to work now.  is there a problem using y and x as variables?

Comment: First, do you have 'Option Explicit' specified? If not, it is a good habit to always have one... saves lots of debug time.  Second, did you specify a Dim statement for your variables, and if so, what TYPE were Y and X. 892 years ago, I have a vague recollection of not providing a data type, and the default type would be assigned based on the variable name... can't remember if that was VBA, Visual Basic, Fortran, COBOL, of rock and chisel.

Comment: I did dim the variables as Integers I need to check the Option Explicit but I think I did that also, but I am not sure.  you are showing your age as I am as I thought I remembered something like that back in Fortran also but it has been too long.  I want to thank you for your help.  I have posted anything before to a site for help but this helped me work though the issue.